# CSS perspective: fit the trapezoid inside container bounds

Tags: javascript, css, webkit-perspective

I have this snippet which puts a full-page `<canvas>` element into a 45-degree perspective using CSS. However, the transformed canvas exceeds the page's bounds and is clipped:

```js
window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  // draw a gradient on the canvas
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#ff0000');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, '#ffff00');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#00ff00');
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(45deg);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 50vw;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

How would I ensure the entire canvas stays within the page's bounds (bottom side of the trapezoid should have the exact same width as the page), while maintaining the perspective effect? Either CSS or JavaScript solutions are fine, as long as they work with any page size.

Answer (score 0):

translate it backwards using `translateZ`

look for a comment in CSS

```js
window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  // draw a gradient on the canvas
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#ff0000');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, '#ffff00');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#00ff00');
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* added translation here */
  transform: translateZ(-50vmax) rotateX(45deg);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 50vw;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is not adequate for all page sizes. Try clicking "full page" on the snippet, or running it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qygYEd).

Comment: thats just a technique .. value can be in percentages or viewport units.. and can be altered with media query